# If wrappers can replace instance methods, why use types.MethodType at all?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wrapper

So if I have a class with method `foo`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def foo(self):
        return "Hey I am called %s." % self.name
```

and I decide to make a wrapper:

```
def bar(obj, func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print "I am %d years old." % obj.age
        return func(*args, **Kwargs)
    return inner
```

And later on I just go ahead and replace `obj.foo` on an instance of the `A` class, all's well.

```
Stick = A('Stick', 32)
Stick.foo = bar(Stick, Stick.foo)
Stick.foo()
>>> I am 32 years old.
>>> Hey I am called Stick.
```

So that's fine, but if I omit the `return func(*args, **kwargs)` bit, it acts as though it just replaces the method in the same way as one might expect when using `types.MethodType` to replace an instance method on the fly.

```
def bar(obj):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return "I am %d years old." % obj.age
    return inner
Stick.foo = bar(Stick)
Stick.foo()
>>> I am 32 years old.
```

So perhaps there is some kind of overhead incurred in this way, or some other deficit to this way of implementing a strategy pattern, but... this seems to work out pretty well. Compared to bringing in `types.MethodType` for the purpose of writing functions that have the word `self` in them, it is unclear to me as to why importing `types.MethodType` would be preferred to simply using wrappers that don't return the original method, or by using the assignment syntax instead of the @decorator way of doing things.

I feel I often see the suggestion of using the `types` library where someone seems to want something like a strategy pattern - not always, but often enough to where it appears that many users may be overlooking something which Python seems to already be equipped to handle. As in [this speech from PyCon 2009](http://bitworking.org/news/428/the-lack-of-design-patterns-in-python-pycon-2009) where clear examples are given that urge the coder to 'look to the language first' for features which may already exist before asking for changes -- I believe the arc of his speech is more aimed at over-coding or going out and writing a PEP, but I think it applies here too -- should one turn to a library when a wrapper is all they needed?

So unless there is something that makes the `types` approach more compelling, in which case the answer is obvious, here's what I'm asking: *In which situation(s) is it preferred to use `types.MethodType` as opposed to simply writing wrappers like those I've demonstrated?*

Comment: Source for preferring `types.MethodType`? Without a real example it's hard to answer your question. Normal higher-order functions (what you seem to be calling decorators) are fine for most cases, in my experience.

Comment: It sort of sounds like you're suggesting one could write a bunch of higher-order functions (or even plain functions) and assign them to an object-instance instead of defining them at the class level in order to avoid something?  Another comment: this feels javascripty.

Comment: @erewok - maybe not quite THAT bonkers, but I see what you did there. I don't know what I'm 'avoiding' though; if I'm just talking about strategy patterns for example, this seems pretty awesome.

Comment: @agf - Hmm, I think my language is misleading - it looks like that's what I'm asking, doesn't it? I'm going to reword my question - I am more curious I guess as to why a library has an aspect to it that appears AFAICT to simply mimic a language feature.

Comment: @Stick That makes more sense. You're right, all methods do is automatically pass in the object they're bound to, rather than you having to do it manually. In Python 3, there is literally no difference between an unbound method and a function; in Python 2 they are slightly different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly rare occurrence that you'd need or want to use *anything* in the `types` module, though I will admit to having subclassed `types.ModuleType` in the past for [flexmock](https://github.com/kw/flexmock/commit/ca5f686e6253c9ae880465f06d9506cff039f27f). The primary purpose of this module is mainly to give you names for classes that would otherwise be awkward to refer to, with the caveat that some of them are also known by things like `dict` or `int`.

It is only very rarely that you'd actually need to use these names to construct or subclass something. So what do you do with something like `types.MethodType`? Use it for introspection.

Say you wanted to write an automatic documentation generator. Maybe you hand your autodoc the module in question. Using `types.FunctionType`, `types.TypeType`, and maybe `types.ClassType` (for old-style classes), you can figure out what things in the module are functions and classes and call appropriate documentation formatters for each. For each class, you can iterate through its members and use `types.MethodType` to sort out the class's methods from its other attributes and document each as appropriate.

Comment: All right, cool. It is interesting to see just how many SO solutions for implementing new methods at runtime reference this library. That was what prompted my question; I typically assume that if I find a way to do something with less code or less effort, I must be doing it wrong. However, in this rare instance, it appears I was actually onto something!